# Shortcut to open source files in Source Insight

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, source-insight

I am new to Source Insight and wuld like to know the keyboard shortcuts.
For example -  in eclipse to open source file we can use **Ctrl+Shift+R**. Is there such shortcuts in source insight?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up all the keyboard shortcuts via the "Options->Key assignments" menu. The standard shortcut for "file open" is CTRL-O but you can change it if you like.